# query outlook categories msaccess

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I'd like to be able to link my inbox in msaccess such that I can query mail against categories.

I cannot seem to figure it out.

I can link the inbox table, but the categories seemed to be stored elsewhere.

Comment: Please show the relevant snippet of your code.

Comment: Are you looking for the flags?  Try FlagIcon, FlagRequest and FlagStatus which are all properties of a MailItem.

Comment: No I am not looking at flags

Comment: It would seem that it is not possible using the method I had tried initially which was the link through ODBC, So to access the categories I will have to do some custom VBA code: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9d0774b3-c7a1-49c9-a329-bd71fa0e7598/linking-access-to-outlook-contacts-not-showing-all-fields

Answer (score 1):

I have never used categories and they are poorly documented which was why I assumed you were after the more obvious Flags.

Categories are held as a comma delimited string in the property `Categories` which I cannot find described in any Microsoft documentation.

If you select a few emails and run the following macro it will display their categories, if any:

```
Sub DsplCategories()

  Dim Exp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem
  Dim NumSelected As Long

  Set Exp = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer

  NumSelected = Exp.Selection.Count

  If NumSelected = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No emails selected"
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      With ItemCrnt
        Debug.Print "From " & .SenderName & "  Categories: " & .Categories
      End With
    Next
  End If

End Sub
```

I hope this is enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks Tony, it has provided me a good start. I'll have to do a bit more work that was originally intended.